# Issue while navigation back to specific screen in iOS

Tags: swift, navigation, storyboard

i have a bit complex scenario to call multiple screen and get back to specific screen in my app UI. I have a homeVC which is embed in navigation controller when user click homeVC it present another screen called detailVC. This is hierarchy of calling screens 
[image]

After submitting an api in LastVC i want to directly navigate to DetailVC screen,i have tried multiple ways but my app get stuck. I have tried,

```
Unwind Segue
```

Through this code i navigate to HomeVC but it also get stuck,

```
self.view.window!.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Main issue is app get stuck and nothing operate in it. How i can make this happend i have tried many solutions but fail to get it done.

Comment: instead present you can use push navigation

Comment: according to demand in project its complusory to use present way. @RajuAbe

Comment: did you ever try with notificationCenter?

Comment: nope, can you explain how to do that? @PALAKMobileTeamLeader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I checked your app flow then your presenting two view controller, Home page present detail view and detail view present Explain vc.

But when you try to present another view on any already presented viewController then may be you get error.

Let me give some logic for that. understand below code and use in your app. maybe it will helpful for you.

HomeViewController:

```
Override func ViewDidLoad()
{


    //Add Obeserver for presenting ExplainVC.

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(PresentExplainVC),name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: “presentexplainvc”),object: nil)


    //Add Obeserver for presenting DetailVC.

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(PresentDetailVC),name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: “presentdetailvc”),object: nil)

}


@objc func PresentExplainVC()
{
 //write code for presenting your ExplainVC
}

@objc func PresentDetailVC()
{
 //write code for presenting your DetailVC
}
```

DetailVC:

when you present explainVC then use below code

```
self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("presentexplainvc"), object: nil)
        })
```

ExplainVC:

```
Override func ViewDidLoad()
{

 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(PresentDetailVCFromHome),name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: “presentdetailvcfromhome”),object: nil)

}


@objc func PresentDetailVCFromHome()
{
 self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
 NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("presentdetailvc"), object: nil)
        })
}
```

VC1:(whatever its List or form)

```
Override func ViewDidLoad()
{

 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(PopviewtoexplainVC),name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: “popviewtoexplainvc”),object: nil)

}


@objc func PopviewtoexplainVC()
{


DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("presentdetailvcfromhome"), object: nil)
        })
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
}
```

VC2:(whatever its List or form)

```
Override func ViewDidLoad()
{

 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,selector: #selector(PopviewtoVC1),name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: “popviewtovc1”),object: nil)

}


@objc func PopviewtoVC1()
{


DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("popviewtoexplainvc"), object: nil)
     })   
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
}
```

LastVC:

Use below code for pop to DetailVC

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
   NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("popviewtovc1"), object: nil)

})
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```